# Reusing table definition in table-valued functions and views

Tags: sql-server

I have several user defined table-valued functions and one view which has the same columns in returned table. How can I reuse return table definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>In SQL Server 2008, you can use a [User-Defined Table Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526.aspx).</strike>

Prepare for a lot of copy-and-pasting.

(Edit: Apparently you *can't* return a UDTT from a UDF.  It would have made sense, but there's just no syntax for it.  So it's either copy and paste, or use an inline table-valued UDF if you can.)

Comment: I can use any. I;m just not sure what syntax I should use. I tried returning table type but SQL Server says function should return scalar value. Do you have any idea what syntax I should use?

Comment: @Sergej: As I mentioned in my edit, you can't use a UDTT in this case.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.  It seems like you should be able to, but there is no syntax that works.